# PowerShell function to chunk the pipe line objects into arrays can't get the correct result

Tags: powershell, pipeline

I'm learning PowerShell and trying to write a function to chunk the pipe line objects into arrays. If the user provid a scriptblock $Process, the function will apply the scriptblock to each of the pipe line objects before send them out to the pipe line (not implemented yet in the below code). So let's say giving the parameter $InputObject as `1, 2, 3, 4, 5` and $ElementsPerChunk as `2`, then the function should return 3 arrays `@(1, 2), @(3, 4), @(5)`. Below is my current code:

```
function Chunk-Object
{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true,
                   ValueFromPipeline = $true,
                   ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName = $true)] [object[]] $InputObject,
        [Parameter()] [scriptblock] $Process,
        [Parameter()] [int] $ElementsPerChunk
    )

    Begin {
        $cache = @();
        $index = 0;
    }
    Process {
        if($cache.Length -eq $ElementsPerChunk) {
            # if we collected $ElementsPerChunk elements in an array, sent it out to the pipe line
            Write-Output $cache;

            # Then we add the current pipe line object to the array and set the $index as 1
            $cache = @($_);
            $index = 1;
        }
        else {
            $cache += $_;
            $index++;
        }

    }
    End {
        # Here we check if there are anything still in $cache, if so, just sent out it to pipe line
        if($cache) {
            Write-Output $cache;
        }
    }
}


echo 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 | Chunk-Object -ElementsPerChunk 2;
Write-Host "=============================================================================";
(echo 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 | Chunk-Object -ElementsPerChunk 2).gettype();
Write-Host "=============================================================================";
(echo 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 | Chunk-Object -ElementsPerChunk 2).length;
```

When I execute the code, I got:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
=============================================================================

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType                                                                                                                                          
-------- -------- ----                                     --------                                                                                                                                          
True     True     Object[]                                 System.Array                                                                                                                                      
=============================================================================
7
```

As you can see, the result is an array and contains 7 elements. What I expected from the result is 4 elements: `@(1, 2), @(3, 4), @(5, 6), @(7)`. Can anyone help me to check my code and explain the issue? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the pipeline is "unrolling" each of your chunk arrays as you return them from the process block.  Try making this change in the Process block where you return the array:

```
Write-Output (,$cache);
```

That will make the return a 2D array, and then it will "unroll" into a single array instead of individual array elements.

Comment: It's not a 2D array, it's an array itself has been put into a single-element array. Actually I think your code should work and not tested yet. However, I want to know where this "feature" was described and how do you know it? I tried to search PowerShell specification both version 2 and version 3 and can't find the corresponding description. Thank you!

Comment: The first element of $cache is $cache[0].  The same element of (,$cache) would be (,$cache)[0][0].  Maybe "2D" isn't exactly the correct term, but if it isn't I'm not sure what it should be.  I'd have to dig through the specs to find exactly where it is, but I know this from experience going back as far as the B3 release of Monad.